# Derived exception class not caught

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

Starting to use the googletest ASSERT_THROW clause, it seems that 'sometimes' the base type of the thrown exception is handled.  I reduced the relevant code section to this:

```
// myexception.h
struct myexception : public std::logic_error {
   myexception(const char* what):std::logic_error(what){}
};
void throwMy();

// myexception.cpp
void throwMy(){ throw myexception(NULL); }
```

This is my test code:

```
//
void localThrowMy(){ throw myexception(""); }

// test code, based upon the ASSERT_THROW macro
try {
  throwMy();        // outputs "logic_error"
  //localThrowMy(); // would output "what I expected"
}
catch( myexception & ) { cout << "what I expected"; }
catch( std::logic_error & ) { cout << "logic_error"; } // my addition
catch(...) { cout << "mmmh."; }
```

The strange thing is: if I declare the `throwMy` function in the same compilation unit as the test code, "what I expected" is output.  If it's in another unit, the test outputs "logic_error.".

- g++ --version: (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
- ld --version: (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.20.1-system.20100303

Is this code correct?  Could the linker be in error here?

Comment: Can you post a complete compilable example, including `#include` directives? I can't reproduce the problem with the code posted.

Comment: Is it possible that the definition of your class is nested into an unnamed namespace? These would cause different types in each translation unit.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Even so, it would be caught by the `catch (std::logic_error&)`, not the `catch(...)`.

Comment: @rodrigo: that's my mistake, too: it actually outputs 'logic_error'... :(

Comment: @xtofl Ahhh, maybe because the `std::string` constructor throws a `logic_error` in case a `NULL` is passed in the constructor? You can check easily by printing the return of `what()`. What a funny coincidence!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mea Culpa.

Once again, [select wasn't broken](http://www.travisswicegood.com/2009/01/04/select-isn-t-broken/).

The `logic_error` was thrown within the `std::string` constructor: "basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid".  I falsely deduced that there was a problem with the inheritance; it was a plain case of [pebkac](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pebkac).

Actually, I didn't know.  But you [can't pass a null pointer](http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/do-not-pass-null-to-stdstring-constructor/) into the `std::string` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`std::logic_error` constructor receives a `std::string&` as argument, not a `const char *`. So passing `NULL` is undefined behavior.

Consider using a `std::string&` too for `myexception`.